# Python 2.7 для Windows 7 x64 пишет что он "on win32". Почему?

Tags: python, windows, x86-64

Почему при запуске установленного `Python 2.7.13` (`Windows x86-64 MSI installer`) среда выдаёт информацию о версии следующего вида:

`Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC c.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`?

Система, под которой запускаю: `Windows 7 Ultimate x64`. Но почему среда не поддерживает x64, и пишет `... on win32`? Также при запуске своей программы, вижу по времени выполнения то, что поддержки x64 нет, и работает также долго, как и на 32-х разрядной системе.

Какой установщик необходимо использовать, чтобы иметь полноценную поддержку x64? Неужели, кроме как установкой `Python 3` не обойтись больше ничем?

Comment: >>>import platform
>>>platform.architecture()[0]

Что выдает?

Comment: @nick_gabpe выдает `64bit`

Comment: У Вас стоит 64битный Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Python 2.7.13` – версия Python

`(v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40)` – номер ревизии и время сборки

`[MSC c.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]` – скомпилено при помощи MSC компилятора для 64 битной платформы

`on win32` – вы на Windows платформе (вне зависимости от количества битов)